# Reset network settings on 6S

Tags: iphone

I have  followed the instructions •Reset Network Settings by tapping Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings. But prior to tapping "reset network settings" I want to be sure that I do not have my data deleted in the process. In other words it will not go back to factory settings will it? I made that error once and cost me much work wise.

Comment: Pressing 'Reset Network Settings' will remove saved wifi passwords, connections to Bluetooth devices (speakers, smart watches, fitness trackers), and forget all of your wifi connections. This will not delete any of your other settings, app data, personal data, etc. You can press that button without fear.